# how do I dynamically updated a UILabel's text programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit, uilabel

I would like to use a simple function to update the text inside a UIlabel.  I'm getting the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I've looked into this problem and found this excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) that suggested using optional binding/guard statements.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    var chooseButton: UIButton!
    var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let btn = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
        btn.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 2
        btn.setTitle("Pick a side", for: .normal)
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickMe), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.height/2
        self.view.addSubview(btn)

        let nameLabel = UILabel()

        nameLabel.text = "Here is your side"
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 200, height: 100)
        self.view.addSubview(nameLabel)


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @objc func clickMe(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button Clicked")
        self.nameLabel.text = "updated title"

    }

}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? How have you updated your code according to the post you linked to?

Comment: It crashes when I press the button.

Comment: I assume nameLabel isn't connected in the storyborad?

Comment: I've created everything programmatically.

Comment: `let nameLabel = UILabel()` must be `self.nameLabel = UILabel()` (you don't need to add _self_, but I wanted to emphasise the difference between the two lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are adding the label manually in loadView but you are creating a local label object that you add to the view and not your class property so the class property `nameLabel` is always nil

Change

```
let nameLabel = UILabel()
```

to

```
self.nameLabel = UILabel()
```